# How can I access my products in this JSON array?

Tags: json

I'm trying to access my products based on subcategory title. have I structured my json in a way that makes that impossible?

let data = filename.json gets the file (using Axios).
but then data["sub cat title 1"] gets me nothing.

How should I restructure?
Thanks

```
[
    {
        "subcategoryTitle": "sub cat title 1",
        "subcategoryItems": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "title": "name 1",
                "sku": "sku 1",
                "image": "img/path to image",
                "description": "Cream beans medium rich breve cinnamon latte. White pumpkin spice kopi-luwak sugar foam frappuccino dark. Brewed arabica, dripper arabica as milk turkish medium."
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "subcategoryTitle": "sub cat title 2",
        "subcategoryItems": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "title": "name 2",
                "sku": "sku 2",
                "image": "img/path to image"
                "description": "Cream beans medium rich breve cinnamon latte. White pumpkin spice kopi-luwak sugar foam frappuccino dark. Brewed arabica, dripper arabica as milk turkish medium."
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "title": "name 2",
                "sku": "sku 2",
                "image": "img/path to image",
                "description": "Cream beans medium rich breve cinnamon latte. White pumpkin spice kopi-luwak sugar foam frappuccino dark. Brewed arabica, dripper arabica as milk turkish medium."
            }
        ]
    }  
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON is an array of objects. With the current format, you'd have to `find()` the element of the array with the correct title:

```
let items = data.find(o => o.subcategoryTitle == "sub cat title 1").subcategoryItems;
```

If you'd like to restructure so it's keyed by the title, you can have the top level be just an object, not an array, with keys being titles and values being the item arrays:

```
{
    "sub cat title 1": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "name 1",
            "sku": "sku 1",
            "image": "img/path to image",
            "description": "Cream beans medium rich breve cinnamon latte. White pumpkin spice kopi-luwak sugar foam frappuccino dark. Brewed arabica, dripper arabica as milk turkish medium."
        }
    ],
    "sub cat title 2": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "name 2",
            "sku": "sku 2",
            "image": "img/path to image"
            "description": "Cream beans medium rich breve cinnamon latte. White pumpkin spice kopi-luwak sugar foam frappuccino dark. Brewed arabica, dripper arabica as milk turkish medium."
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "name 2",
            "sku": "sku 2",
            "image": "img/path to image",
            "description": "Cream beans medium rich breve cinnamon latte. White pumpkin spice kopi-luwak sugar foam frappuccino dark. Brewed arabica, dripper arabica as milk turkish medium."
        }
    ]
}
```

With this structure just `data["sub cat title 1"]` would get you the array of items for that subcategory. You can of course make the values objects containing the arrays if they need to store more information.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: With the way you've structured the data now, is there any way to get the "sub cat title 1", and "sub cat title 2"? 

I'm using Vue to show the array of products, and I'd like to be able to pull out the title of each category

Comment: @mediabloke Not familiar with Vue, but as I've structured it, it's an object, not an array. If you get an array of products somehow, you must have had the key to begin with (it's the only way you could have gotten the array), unless using something like `Object.values(data)` - in which case there's the similar `Object.keys(data)` you could use, or simply `Object.entries(data)` for both.